# Excel password recovery in Python

Tags: python, excel

Below I have been working on a Excel password recovery tool for work as we have had a few occasions where project managers have password protected excels and then forgot the password and they have lost weeks of work because of this.

The below code seems to be running but doesn't get past the first word in the wordlist and then paste that the password has been found.

Example of output:

in cmd

```
C:\Users\eldri\OneDrive\Desktop>python xlcrka.py
[+] Excel to attack: C:\Users\eldri\OneDrive\Desktop\target.xlsx
[+] Wordlist: C:\Users\eldri\OneDrive\Desktop\Wordlists\rockyou.txt
[-] Password attempt: 123456
[+] Password Found: 123456
```

in Pycharm Terminal

```
C:\Users\eldri\PycharmProjects\CAPTCHA\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/eldri/PycharmProjects/Bad codes/xlcrka.py"
[+] Excel to attack: C:\Users\eldri\OneDrive\Desktop\target.xlsx
[+] Wordlist: C:\Users\eldri\OneDrive\Desktop\Wordlists\rockyou.txt
[-] Password attempt: 123456
[+] Password Found: 123456
```

Below is the code I have got so far:

```
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
from win32com.client import Dispatch

file = raw_input('[+] Excel to attack: ')
wordlist = raw_input('[+] Wordlist: ')

word = open(wordlist, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
allpass = word.readlines()
word.close()

for password in allpass:
    password = password.strip()
    print ("[-] Password attempt: "+password)
    instance = Dispatch('Excel.Application')

    try:
        instance.Workbooks.Open(file, False, True, None, password)
        print ("[+] Password Found: "+password)
        break

    except:
        pass
```

**The outcome I want to achieve**:
Learn why this is not working.
see whether anyone has any ideas on how to improve

**Output for the code:**
To go through the wordlist and find the correct password and print the password

Comment: You are expecting that `instance.Workbooks.Open(file, False, True, None, password)` raises an exception when the password is invalid. On the first password, it does not raise an exception and the code finishes.

Comment: So is this why it prints password found with the same value?

Comment: what is the format of rockyou.txt?

Comment: @Davidsherriff rockyou is a txt format in notepad. Thank you so much again.

Comment: @Ooo I meant is the file made up of a word followed by a new line or word, word for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what you where missing, you needed a `else: break` in the try except statement so that once the password was found the loop will break and did not carry on printing incorrect password found statements. You also needed `instance.Quit()` to prevent the program from continuing the print incorrect password found statements if you re-ran the code. I moved `instance` from the loop as you don't need to open a new instance every time (that might have caused some issues thinking about it)

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from pywintypes import com_error

file = input('[+] Excel to attack: ')
wordlist = input('[+] Wordlist: ')
instance = Dispatch('Excel.Application')

word = open(wordlist, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
allpass = word.readlines()
word.close()

for password in allpass:
    password = password.rstrip()
    print("[-] Password attempt: " + password)
    try:
        instance.Workbooks.Open(file, False, True, None, password)
        print("[+] Password Found: " + password)
    except com_error:
        instance.Workbooks.Close()
    else:
        instance.Workbooks.Close()
        instance.Quit()
        break
```

I also imported `com_error` from `pywintypes` for the exception handling, you should try to avoid a bare `except` statement as that could cause issues and is not good practice.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was so close but couldn't finish the code. would you add com_error in all your codes?

I just ran the code and got this error?:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xlcrka.py", line 9, in <module>
    allpass = word.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\uk20071143\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 3149: character maps to <undefined>

what does this mean?

Comment: You dont need to add `com_error` to all your codes, it is only in the code as `instanceWordkbooks.Open` throws an `com_error` exception when the password is incorrect. As for the error that could be my bad, I removed your decode and error ignore whilst i was testing it on my computer, I'll add those back and see if it works now

Comment: Okay, thank you I will take on board. How did you bypass the decode and error ignore? I tried everything but I couldn't do it? Thank you so much for your help it is really appreciated. Been trying to work out how to finish the password tool for ages. Do you have any good websites to learn python or did you got to uni and learn it?

Comment: I made a simple text file that probably didnt resemble the one you use in order to test the code, hence I didnt need decode and ignore. I started learning python at uni but I've learned the most just using python to solve problems at work. I do recommend OpenEDG, they have basic and itermediate python courses that follow the Python Institute syllabus, the courses are free too so worth checking out along with Python Institute

Comment: sorry to bother you again but even with the correct password, it doesn't seem to be finding the password? it just attempts and moves on to the next?

Comment: Thank you, I have just got on to the OpenEDG page and have signed up now. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `break` after `print ("[+] Password Found: "+password)` ends the loop. So as long as `Workbooks.Open` doesn't raise you will never try any other password.

I don't know how `Workbooks.Open` works but you might want to check for its return value to know if you've found the right password.

Also a try/except like that will mute any error so you can't know if anything wrong happened, at least replace it with:

```
import traceback

...

except Exception as ecx:
    traceback.print_exc()
    # or
    print(exc)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried what you suggested and no errors comes up, it just shows the same output as above unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find out what's going on, remove the try-block from the code.

Your code is structured in such a way that

`instance.Workbooks.Open(file, False, True, None, password)`

is supposed to raise some general error which you do not specify. In your sample case it does not and hence it continues and ends.

Remove the 'try-block' and try to access any method on the open workbook and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the try block and used a different method and it seems to be printing the whole rockyou.txt list: [-] Password attempt: happygolucky for example.

Comment: So its means i tried all passwords ?
Can you edit your question with the new code ?