# Copy files with their creation date in a specific range

Tags: python, shutil

'''I am currently trying to copy files from one folder to another folder using shutil but I can't seem to get it to work, the process is saying it has finished but nothing happens?'''

The current criteria I have added raw_input that lets the user choose file extension.
The next criteria I am looking to add is a date range function so I can choose a date range for example:
17/07/2020 to 04/08/2020 or the day's date.

********************************UPDATED CODE*******************************

```
import os
import shutil
import os.path, time
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

os.chdir('C://')
src = ("C:/Users/eldri/OneDrive/Desktop/")
dst = ("C:/Users/eldri/OneDrive/Desktop/output")
ext = raw_input("[+] File format: ")
created = (" last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(src)))
start = raw_input("[+] Date start: ")
end = raw_input("[+] Date end: ")

def date_to_num(date):
    return int("".join(date.split('/')[::-1]))

def date_in_range(date, start, end):
    return date_to_num(date) > date_to_num(start) and date_to_num(date) < date_to_num(end)

for filename in os.listdir(src):
    if filename.endswith('.'+ext) and created.startswith(start) and created.endswith(end):
        shutil.copy( src + filename, dst)
        print("[+] File transferred "+filename + created)
    else:
        print("[+] File not transferred "+filename + created)
        
print("[+] Transfer complete")
```

I was looking at maybe pandas? but not sure as still quite new to python.

```
example on terminal
file extension = .csv
startdate = 12/05/2020
enddate = 07/08/2020
```

once the user has input these fields it would copy only the required files over.

The current output of the created files are:

```
[+] File transferred BASE1011.xls last modified: Fri Jul 17 10:11:40 2020
[+] File transferred BASE1112.xls last modified: Fri Jul 17 10:11:40 2020
[+] File transferred BASE1213.xls last modified: Fri Jul 17 10:11:40 2020
[+] File transferred BASE1314.xls last modified: Fri Jul 17 10:11:40 2020
[+] File transferred BASE1415.xls last modified: Fri Jul 17 10:11:40 2020
```

I want these to be in an easier format for user input as explained above:
example: start 12/05/2020 end date = 07/08/2020

Thank you for your help, I am not the best at python but I am trying to learn so any help would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: you might find this answer useful for what you are trying to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501288/13906433

Comment: Thank you @Davidsherriff can I ask whether there is a way to only cp files created/ modified between two dates?

I have updated my question#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've carried on your work using `time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(src))` and created a function `dateRange(createdDate, startDate, endDate)` that uses `datetime` to convert the strings into datetime objects and returns True or False if the created date falls between start and end dates

```
import os
import shutil
import time
from datetime import datetime

src = "C:/Users/eldri/OneDrive/Desktop/"
dst = "C:/Users/eldri/OneDrive/Desktop/output"
ext = input("[+] File format: ")  # "txt"
start = input("[+] Date start: ")  # "01/07/2020"
end = input("[+] Date end: ")  # "30/07/2020"


def dateRange(createdDate, startDate, endDate):
    """determines if date is in range"""
    createdDate = datetime.strptime(createdDate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
    startDate = datetime.strptime(startDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
    endDate = datetime.strptime(endDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
    return startDate < createdDate < endDate


for filename in os.listdir(src):
    created = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(src + filename))
    if filename.endswith('.' + ext) and dateRange(created, start, end):
        shutil.copy(src + filename, dst)
        print("[+] File transferred " + filename + created)
    else:
        print("[+] File not transferred " + filename + created)

print("[+] Transfer complete")
```

I've added examples at the end of the `ext`, `start`, and `end` variables to provide an idea of the format

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have copied the code over and it run perfectly, I am going to research the date time as never used it before. So i can use input rather then raw_input? is that better then raw_input? also can I ask when you get time can you have a look at my other post please if you don't mind.
[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157777/new-to-python-excel-password-cracker-in-python [link]

Comment: You're welcome. `input` is a built in python method, no need to import anything, it will return a string. If you needed a integer input for example you can use `number = int(input("please enter a integer: ")`
Yes I will have a look at your other post :)

Comment: Thank you so much for for your help, I will have a few test codes now using the number = int(input("please enter a integer: "). Excellent thank you, been struggling for a while, seem to be very hit and miss with getting codes write and then I follow the rabbit and then get screwed lol

Comment: Can i ask whether you know how to add a progress bar to this at all?
I tried
progressbar = tqdm(os.listdir(src))

for item in progressbar:
    time.sleep(0.010)
    pass

but it only counts the files in the folder and measures time it takes to count them, not how long it takes to transfer?

Comment: @Ooo I might have an idea to get an estimate.... Let me get back to you

Comment: @Ooo please refer to your other question, hopefully that will help you get started

Answer (score 1):

For specific range you can:

create a function that parse the date to a number:

```
def date_to_num(date):
    return int("".join(date.split('/')[::-1]))

def date_in_range(date, start, end):
    return date_to_num(date) > date_to_num(start) and date_to_num(date) < date_to_num(end)
```

And then use it like that:

```
date_in_range("03/02/2020", "01/01/2020", "05/05/2020")
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your help.
Really sorry but I am still really new to python, I have updated the code in the question, is that correct? I have tried it and the files are not transferring still.
[+] File format: csv
[+] Date start: 06/07/2020
[+] Date end: 06/08/2020

Comment: @Ooo No problems :), Can you attach a code or an example so I can understand what didn't work?

Comment: I have updated the questions code to add in the def date_to_num and def date_in_range.
'''
[+] File format: csv
[+] Date start: 06/08/2020
[+] Date end: 06/08/2020
[+] File not transferred 02002.csv last modified: Thu Aug  6 15:26:24 2020
'''
The code works if I do not put a date but when I put a date range in it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ooo you've added my function but didn't call them anywhere :/ You need to call the `date_in_range` funcion with your date and range and it should work

Comment: I have also just realised that created = (" last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(src))) does not work.